# Is there a way to perform validation for apex:inputField?

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation

I am creating a form in Visualforce. Since my form is a bit long, it is hard for users to remember the error message at the top and revise it. On top of the error message, I want to create a validation when users typing in their information.

For example, there are 2 field, users name and email. Users cannot leave the name field blank, if so, I want to show a message of "This field is required to fill in" beside the field. And for email field, I want to have another message to remind users to insert a valid email.

Is there anyway in visualforce to do so? Thanks for your help.

---

Here is my updated visualforce code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Artist__c" extensions="extattachfile" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<style type="text/css">
h1 {font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold;}
h2 {font-size: ;}
p { width:100%;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;}
.reddot {color: red; font-size:120%;}
.textarea { height:200px; 
            width:300px;
            border-radius: 5px;}
.url {width:300px;}
.title {font-size:175%;}
.standard {width: 310px;}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    /* For desktop: */
p { width:890px;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;}
}
.color {
    background-color: #F7F6D2;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
</style>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includescript value="{!$Resource.jQuery}"></apex:includescript>
<apex:includescript value="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.6/jquery.validate.min.js"></apex:includescript>
<apex:includescript value="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></apex:includescript>
<apex:includescript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></apex:includescript>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />    
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.6/jquery.validate.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
</head>    

 <script>
        $ = jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[id$=artistform]').validate();             

            $('[id$=chiname]').rules("add",{
                required: true,
            });     

            $('[id$=email]').rules("add",{
                required: true,
                email: true
            });      

            /* Customised the messages */
           jQuery.validator.messages.required = "<label style='color:red'>This field is required</label>"; 

        });
    </script>     

<apex:form styleclass="form" id="artistform">
   <apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageMessages />
<div><b class="title">Artist Submission Form</b></div><br/>
<br/>
     <h1>Artist / Group Information</h1>
     <br/><br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2>Artist / Group Name (Chinese)</h2><br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputText value="{!artist.Artist_Group_Name_Chinese__c}" id="chiname"/ >
     <apex:outputlabel id="op2" />
     </apex:panelGroup>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >Artist / Group Name (English)</h2><br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Artist_Group_Name_English__c}" label="" id="engname"/>
     </apex:panelGroup>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >Artist / Group Biography (Chinese)</h2><br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Artist_Group_Biography_Chinese__c}" label="" styleClass="textarea" id="chibio"/>
     </apex:panelGroup>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >Artist / Group Biography (English)</h2><br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Artist_Group_Biography_English__c}" label="" styleClass="textarea" id="engbio"/>
     </apex:panelGroup>
     <br/><br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="heading">
     <h1>Name and Roles of Group Members (if applicable)</h1>
     <br/>
     <br/><br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2>Name and Roles of Group Members</h2><br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value=""/><br/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Member_Name_Role__c}" label="" styleClass="textarea"/><br/>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >Photo of Artist/ Group : max 3 attachments</h2><br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/>
     <br/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputFile value="{!objAttachment.body}" fileName="{!objAttachment.name}" required="false" id="photo"/><br/></apex:panelGroup>
     <apex:inputFile value="{!objAttachment2.body}" fileName="{!objAttachment2.name}" required="false" /><br/>
     <apex:inputFile value="{!objAttachment3.body}" fileName="{!objAttachment3.name}" required="false" />
     <br/><br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2>Website</h2><outputtext/><apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value=""/><br/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Website__c}" label="" styleClass="url" id="web"/><br/>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >Facebook</h2><apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value=""/><br/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Facebook__c}" label="" styleClass="url" id="facebook"/><br/>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >SoundCloud</h2><apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value=""/><br/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.SoundCloud__c}" label="" styleClass="url" id="soundcloud"/><br/>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >YouTube</h2><apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value=""/><br/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.YouTube__c}" label="" styleClass="url" id="youtube"/>
     <br/>      </div>
<br/><br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2>Technical Rider: max 1 attachment</h2><br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value=""/><br/>
     <apex:inputFile value="{!objAttachmentt.body}" fileName="{!objAttachmentt.name}" /><br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2>Stage Plot: max 1 attachment</h2>
     <br/>
<apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value=""/><br/>

     <apex:inputFile value="{!objAttachments.body}" fileName="{!objAttachments.name}" required="false" /><br/><br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="heading">
     <h1>Contact Information </h1> <br/><br/>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2>Contact Person </h2><apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/><br/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Contact_Person__c}" label="" id="contactperson"/>
     <br/>
     </apex:panelGroup>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2 >Contact No. </h2><apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/><br/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Contact_Number__c}" label="" id="contactno"/>
     <br/>
     </apex:panelGroup>      </div>
<br/>
      <div class="standard">
     <h2>Email </h2><apex:outputText styleClass="reddot" value="*"/><br/>
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="col02 requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:panelGroup styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!artist.Email__c}" label="" id="email"/>
     <br/>
     </apex:panelGroup>      </div>
<br/>
<br/>
      <div>

        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
      </div>

<script>
 var addclass = 'color';
var $cols = $('.standard').click(function(e) {
    $cols.removeClass(addclass);
    $(this).addClass(addclass);
});

</script>

</apex:pageBlock>       
</apex:form>
<apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I take it you're not using a custom controller? What have you tried? JavaScript or jQuery could be one route.

Comment: I have found one page, https://th3silverlining.com/2010/03/02/visualforce-form-validation-enhanced/. But I have faced problem that nothing occured... And I will update more information by editing.

Comment: Even I follow the format from the link, it still doesn't work. Is there any problem for the script source? Or static resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked in the comment seems to be referencing `<apex:inputText>` tags which differ slightly from `<apex:inputField>` in that the latter directly references a field, or as Salesforce better put it:

> An HTML input element for a value that corresponds to a field on a Salesforce object.

The former could be anything.

Assuming you're not using a custom controller, one option is to use jQuery in your Visualforce page.

Assuming you have two fields and a button like below:

```
<apex:inputField id="contactName" value="{!Contact.Name}" />
<apex:inputField id="contactEmail" value="{!Contact.Email}" />
<apex:commandButton id="submitButton" action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
```

You can reference the Ids using `$Component.fieldId`.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name = {!$Component.contactName};
    var email = {!$Component.contactEmail};
    var submit = {!$Component.submitButton};
    var errors = [];

    submit.click(function(e) {
        if (name.val().length() > 32 || email.val().length() > 64) {
            errors.push['A field is too long.'];
        }

        // More validation...

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, one option could also be to simply use HTML 5 validation. As long as you include `docType="html-5.0"` in the `<apex:page>` tag, you can use things like `html-type="email"` or `html-required` in the `<apex:inputField>`.

As an example:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!artist.Email__c}" label="" id="email" html-type="email" html-required="true" />
```

This would validate on the fly, by the field, as you want.

**Edit**

Turns out `required` is standard so `html-required` does nothing.

I wrote a basic Visualforce Page as below which compiled and saved successfully:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText required="true" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I have try a simple one on salesforce, but it still not work...
<apex:page docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputText required="true" html-aria-described‌​by="show"/>
        <span id="show">HI!</span>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

result:
 Error: test line 3, column 60: Attribute name "html-aria-described" associated with an element type "apex:inputText" must be followed by the ' = ' character 
Error Error: Attribute name "html-aria-described" associated with an element type "apex:inputText" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Comment: @alexwong820 You might want to put that question in another SFSE question as this comment section is getting too long. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44080/discussion-on-answer-by-poet-is-there-a-way-to-perform-validation-for-apexinput).

Comment: Is there any good example code to enable visualforce+bootstrap to perform html 5 validations? Thanks in advance.